# Align multiple images/headings on same line - bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to align 3 headings and 2 images on the same line, like so:

Heading Image Heading Image Heading

---

I tried using Bootstrap's media component, like so:

```
<div class="media">

    <h5 class="media-heading">Media heading</h5>
    <img class="media-object pull-left" src="img/img.png" alt="..." />
    <h5 class="media-heading">Media heading</h5>
    <img class="media-object pull-left" src="img/img.png" alt="..." />
    <h5 class="media-heading">Media heading</h5>

</div>
```

But I'm having a hard time getting everything to be on the same line. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: You may want to select one of the answers as best...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Please try this way**

```
<div class="media">

    <h5 class="media-heading pull-left">Media heading</h5>
    <img class="media-object pull-left" src="img/img.png" alt="..." />
    <h5 class="media-heading pull-left">Media heading</h5>
    <img class="media-object pull-left" src="img/img.png" alt="..." />
    <h5 class="media-heading pull-left">Media heading</h5>

</div
```

> 

Comment: Thanks so much to everyone! I used this way.

Answer (score 2):

Add `.media h5 { display:inline }` to your CSS and you're done ;)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mC82w/

**EDIT** Sorry forgot this was inside bootstrap, so I tested it there and found that what you have to also do in addition is to add `.media img { display:inline; }` plus get rid of the `pull left` classes inside the image tags

Comment: I just tried this for a locale line where I have flag image links and text links on a single line using class list-inline. I wrapped a div with img { display: inline; } around the list-inline. It works great!

Comment: happy I could help... hey, why not give my answer a thumbs up (big triangle above the big number next to this answer)...? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just use class="media-heading pull-left" to three headings

```
<div class="media">

       <h5 class="media-heading pull-left">Media heading</h5>
       <img class="media-object pull-left" src="img/img.png" alt="..." />
       <h5 class="media-heading pull-left">Media heading</h5>
       <img class="media-object pull-left" src="img/img.png" alt="..." />
       <h5 class="media-heading pull-left">Media heading</h5>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For these kind of use cases, I learnt that Bootstrap's [thumbnails](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#thumbnails) are quite handy where we could quickly display horizontal lists of images, videos, text etc.

Basic example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
    </a>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```